# Detect the cell row value on tap of a button in that cell in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I have created buttons on the cell content view. I want to detect for which row the button is clicked on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to have your `UIViewController` receive the event by creating a target-action from the `UIButton` to the `UIViewController`, like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in your `UIViewController`'s action method, you can utilize the `UITableView`s `indexPathForCell:` method to obtain the correct `NSIndexPath`:

```
- (void) cellButtonClicked: (id) sender {
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [[btn superview] superview];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
   //do something with indexPath...
}
```

Comment: This method does not work as intended anymore in iOS 7 as there are more views now in UITableViewCells. I was getting back UITableViewCellScrollView's instead of cells with this code periodically.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative that doesn't fall over when apple changes the view hierarchy. Basically find the origin of the button in the coordinate system of the table view. Once you know that you can find the `NSIndexPath` of the row that the `point` is in.

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
    CGPoint buttonOrigin = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonOrigin];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

agree to  **Will**, you have to iterate in iOs7

```
﻿for (UIView *parent = [btn superview]; parent != nil; parent = [parent superview]) {
    if ([parent isKindOfClass: [UITableViewCell class]]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) parent;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: cell];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a simpler solution.

Since in most of the cases each cell represent an object inside an array, you need to define a property in the custom cell class that represent a cell id (in your array) or the cell id that is defined in the server DB and when the button was tapped you can easily get it via `self.id` - id represent the cell id property.